# complex grouping issue in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[theRecords](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[thegroup] [varchar](50) NULL,
[balance] [int] NULL,
)


GO

insert into theRecords values('blue',1,10)
insert into theRecords values('green',1,20)
insert into theRecords values('yellow',2,5)
insert into theRecords values('red',2,4)
insert into theRecords values('white',3,10)
insert into theRecords values('black',4,10)
```

[image]

Firstly, i want to get the sum of balances in each group,then for names that have only one group,the name should be retained,then names that belong to same group should have their name changed too the group name.

```
name  | balance 
1          30
2           9
white      10
black      10
```

Comment: It seems this is a do-it-for-me question!

Comment: The images serve no purpose, they just repeat what you showed in the `insert` statements. Could you instead show what you want the output to look like? I can't figure out what you mean by changing the names.

Comment: _for names that have only one group_ -- all your names are unique, so they all have only one group.

Comment: @Barmar wherever the count of thegroup appears more than once ( the value of thegroup is set as name(group 1 and 2)...blue and green is set to 1,yellow and red is set to 2 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if all the names are the same, I like to compare the minimum to the maximum:

```
select (case when min(name) = max(name) then max(name)
             else thegroup
        end) as name,
       sum(balance) as balance
from theRecords r
group by thegroup;
```

Calculating the `min()` and `max()` is generally  more efficient than a `count(distinct)`.

Comment: Absolutely, the best way

Answer (score 0):

Use group function to group the names with the sum of the balance for each name.

Do this below:

```
select thegroup "name", sum(balance) "balance"
from theRecords group by thegroup order by 1;
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c986f/7/0)

Comment: its working well,except that names whose group count is not greater than one are not retaining their names (i.e 3 should be white and 4 should be black)

Answer (score 0):

```
select case count(distinct name)
         when 1 then name
         else thegroup
       end as name,
       sum(balance) as balance
from theRecords
group by thegroup
```

Comment: <code>select case count(*) when 1 then name
         else thegroup
       end as name,
       sum(balance) as balance
from theRecords
group by thegroup,name </code>

Comment: No, it should just be grouped by thegroup, since that's how you're counting the numberof names.

Comment: I changed `count(*)` to `count(distinct name)`, since I assume there can be duplicate names and we shouldn't count them separately.